# How do I resolve a long running 'Creating project '-MSharp.Meta'...' dialog when creating a new Zebble for Xamarin - Cross Platform Solution project?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin-zebble, zebble

Using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, I am trying to follow the video instructions for creating a new project found here: http://zebble.net/docs/creating-a-new-project

I do the following:

1. I ensure the Zebble extension is installed
2. I click the start screen's 'New Project' link
3. I select 'Zebble for Xamarin - Cross Platform Solution' as project type
4. I name the project 'My application'
5. I click the 'OK' button

What happens next is:

- A small Microsoft Visual Studio dialog appears with the text 'Creating project '-MSharp.Meta'...' and a green loading bar that runs continuously and a Cancel button.
- I get a 'Microsoft Visual Studio is Busy' alert in my taskbar. It says that Visual Studio is waiting on an internal operation to complete.

In the video, the project appears to be created without this long running process.

---

I am running Visual Studio as Administrator.

The following are version details of the Zebble extension I have installed:

- Date Installed: 4/6/2017
- Version: 3.96

The following is the dialog that is continuosly running.

[image]

---

Per Ali's comment, I enabled Visual Studio logging and pulled the following from ActivityLog.xml:

```
125
ERROR
Still unable to load MEF component DLL: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Logic, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
          C:\USERS\FIRSTNAMELASTNAME\APPDATA\LOCAL\MICROSOFT\VISUALSTUDIO\14.0\EXTENSIONS\RHJ3QMIR.2GA\ZebbleVSIX.dll


Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.ExtensibilityHosting.VsShellComponentModelHost
2017/04/06 18:22:44.432
```

Comment: Could you first keep open Output window in your VS and then create new project? please let me know what are the messages/logs are been given to you.

Comment: @Ali I tried keeping the Output window open while creating a new project and nothing was populated. I enabled the VS Activity Log and created a new project and found an error in that log related to Zebble. I have edited the post to include the error. Please let me know if I may provide more information.

Comment: we found the issue on VS 2015 with Update3 and will release new version soon. As a suggestion, Zebble works fine on VS2017.

Comment: @H.Coding, You still can open your project template with VS2015 directly from the directory that you have entered

Comment: @Ali please reply back when the fix version is released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently a bug in Visual Studio 2017 and also VS 15 update 3 in relation to SLN file creation is causing that problem.

Try the following fix:

1. Uninstall the Zebble extension from your Visual Studio and restart it.
2. Install the Zebble extension v 4.2 or later from https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Paymon.ZebbleforXamarin.
3. Create a new Zebble project (see http://zebble.net/docs/creating-a-new-project)
4. Follow the instructions in the file *Android \ -READ-ME-NOW!!!!!!!!!!!!.txt*